# If you temporarily unsubscribe from iTunes Match, will your track list be deleted?

Tags: itunes-match

What happens if you (temporarily) unsubscribe from iTunes Match? Will your library (i.e. the list of all your tracks that Apple stores on their servers) be deleted, or will it only be disabled until you renew your subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find any description in writing saying that there is any grace period for you to access playlists or any other data after you end a subscription period in iTunes Match.

I do recall a warning when signing up for Match that quite explicitly said that I needed to be sure to download all playlists and music from the cloud before my subscription ended. This is in addition to the caution to keep a backup copy of all data (which in the case of playlists would be using iTunes to export the library to an XML file regularly in addition to backing up each track).

Apple could be more generous about keeping non-subscriber data around for a grace period of a day or a week or a month, but why risk this when you can back up everything now and then update that backup with anything that changes a week before your subscription ends?

Answer (score 1):

If your subscription expires, there is a grace period of 90 days before your library will be deleted from iCloud. There will be a message on your Account Info page telling you that iTunes Match has expired and all your stuff on the cloud will be removed in 90 days.

How I Know This: My subscription just expired because I forgot to update my payment information. When I entered my new credit card to renew, my whole library was still there. *Whew!*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! That's a good find and it would be great if either you or somebody else could add either a screenshot or a link to an Apple Support document to confirm it.